# How to split a key-value string into array pairs?

Tags: bash, string

How can I split the following `String` into `key-value` pairs using `bash`?

```
SOURCE="'key1=val 1' 'key2=val 2'"
```

My output goal is:

```
key1=val 1
key2=val 2
```

- I can only input a single String as a variable
- I cannot pass the variable as **array**
- I want to output only the key-value pair plain as is
- I want to honor the quotes, as I don't know how to separate the key-value pairs else
- My keys never contain spaces, but values will

Comment: Will the values contain quotes of any type, such as in `'key1=I'm ok'`?

Comment: If so, they must be written escaped in the value fields

Comment: So, as `'key1=I\'m ok'`?  I'm asking because a single-quoted string can not contain single quotes in the shell, which may have an impact on ways to write solutions.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ment. Apart from that, I'm not fixed in the way the multi-key-value string has to be defined. I could also change it. It's just important that I only can define a single string "in any way" to transport my key-value pairs, and want to echo out each key-value pair individually.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are free to define the `SOURCE` format, so you can make sure, you always have a whitespace between two definitions. In this case, you can remove the ticks at the start and beginning and replace all occerences of `' '` with a newline:

```
echo "$SOURCE" | sed "s/^'//;s/'$//;s/' '/"'\
'/g
```

Note that I need to switch from double quoting to single quoting to quote the line break.

If you also want to remove the backlash from an escaped tick, do

```
echo "'key1=foo bar' 'key2=I\'m okay'" | sed "s/^'//;s/'$//;s/' '/"'\
'"/g;s/\\\\'/'/g"
```

An example to make this fail would be `SOURCE="'key1=foo\' ' 'key2=bar'"`